# Add quotes to values in a string separated by a comma php

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, replace

I have a search box that can contain multiple values using a comma, eg Pasta, tuna, eggs

Im using FULLTEXT mysql search but I need to use some kind of preg_replace to turn Pasta, tuna, eggs into 'Pasta','tuna','eggs'

If I enter this 'Pasta','tuna','eggs' into the search box the results are correct.

Answer (score 13):

Don't use regular expressions for problems that can be solved otherwise. What you want is a simple string replacement:

```
$string = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $string) . "'";
```

You should escape quotes inside the string first, though (don't know what your escape character is, assuming it's backslash):

```
$string = "'" . str_replace(array("'", ","), array("\\'", "','"), $string) . "'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you building an SQL query with the list? If so, you should take some time to make sure the resulting SQL is properly escaped as well.

```
$myList = "pasta, tuna, eggs";

$items = preg_split("/[,\\s]+/", $myList);
$sqlItems = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $sqlItems[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($item) . "'";
}

// Add new list to SQL
$sql .= implode(",", $sqlItems);
```

Comment: This is defienetly a step in the right direction as the string appears to be correct, I get a MYSQL error however with this search:

$query_finder = "SELECT Title, SmallDesc, id, picturesmall FROM recipes WHERE MATCH (Ingredients) AGAINST ('+$include -$exclude' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND type='$type'";

Comment: where the $include is the search term incidentally

Comment: What does the final SQL query look like and what is the SQL error?

Comment: ERROR: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pasta','tuna','eggs' -mushrooms' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND type='0' LIMIT 0, 10' at line 1

query: 
SELECT Title, SmallDesc, id, picturesmall FROM recipes WHERE MATCH (Ingredients) AGAINST ('+'pasta','tuna','eggs' -mushrooms' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND type='0'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any comma in values?

If not you could use something like:

```
preg_replace('/[^,]+/g', '\'\1\'', preg_replace('/\'/g', '\\\'', $text))
```

Answer (score 0):

implode your string, then foreach resulting array and add needed symbols

Answer (score 0):

Guys sorry for the trouble but I've solved my own question! Ive looked at this and it was all wrong to begin with.

I had to replace each , with a space and a plus sign so ", tuna" = " +tuna"

Thanks anyway